# How to simulate walking on slippery surface?

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics

Im programming 2d game in JavaScript canvas. My character can already walk, but now i want him to start with an acceletation until he hits his max speed and when i release the key he should slowly slow down (like on ice). The problem is that when i apply friction force he slows down but then accelerate in the other direction. I got stuck here and cannot find proper tutorial.

Comment: This is due to the nature of physics calculations. You'll have to do a check for when the character reaches a velocity of 0.

Comment: Please can you include some code in your question so that people can advise on what changes you can make? Otherwise all discussions are conceptual and abstract.

Comment: This is really a physics question as it is about basic mechanics. However you can set the frictional force to zero if there is no component of velocity or applied force on the object in the direction parallel to the surface. You could also assume a linear relationship between the frictional force and the above velocity component; however that is somewhat un-physical.

Comment: Easy way is to scale the speed down over time. You have `speed` and `position` Then each step `position += speed;` then `speed *= 1 - drag;` where `drag` is an approximation of friction. The higher the speed the greater the friction and rate that the speed slow. This method will never bring the speed down to zero so you also need to check when speed is close to stop. `If(Math.abs(speed) < 0.1) {speed = 0}` if speed is less than 6 pixels per second (@60 FPS) stop. This works well and is used by most simple 2D games.